# create pyspark dataframe with json string values and schema

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to manually create some dummy pyspark dataframe.

I did the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
data2 = [('{"Time":"2020-08-01T08:14:20.650Z","version":null}')
            ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("raw_json",StringType(),True)
  ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

but i got the error:

```
TypeError: StructType can not accept object '[{"Time:"2020-08-01T08:14:20.650Z","version":null}]' in type <class 'str'>
```

How am i able to put json string into pyspark dataframe as values?

my ideal result is:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                             |             
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| {"Time":"2020-08-01T08:14:20.650Z","version":null}|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of your braces. `data2` should have list of lists - so replace inner parenthesis with square brackets:

```
data2 = [['{"applicationTimeStamp":"2020-08-01T08:14:20.650Z","version":null}']]

schema = StructType([StructField("raw_json",StringType(),True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)

df.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------------------------------------+            
|raw_json                                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"applicationTimeStamp":"2020-08-01T08:14:20.650Z","version":null}|
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It could also work if you specify data2 as a list of tuples, by adding a trailing comma inside the parentheses to specify that it is a tuple.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# Note the trailing comma inside the parentheses
data2 = [('{"applicationTimeStamp":"2020-08-01T08:14:20.650Z","version":null}',)]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("raw_json",StringType(),True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
df.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|raw_json                                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"applicationTimeStamp":"2020-08-01T08:14:20.650Z","version":null}|
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json

rdd = sc.parallelize(data2).map(lambda x: [json.loads(x)]).toDF(schema=['raw_json'])
```